# Jenkins plugins installation giving SHA-256 mismatch error

Tags: networking, docker, ubuntu-16.04, jenkins

I started a fresh container from jenkinsci/blueocean docker image in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server. Container started fine and I am able to see Jenkins console perfectly. When I am trying to install any plugin which isnt bundled with this image it is giving SHA-256 mismatch error like below:-

```
java.io.IOException: Downloaded file /var/jenkins_home/plugins/build-pipeline-plugin.jpi.tmp does not match expected SHA-256, expected 'Ci0bq1rxqEDWF1RklJvBZANp75727gH13+5cFr5HDbs=', actual 'c0qvGjbwCXYFueMfd77NFvIfRPG21Dxt4OxbZ+Gc/7c='
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.throwVerificationFailure(UpdateCenter.java:1902)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.verifyChecksums(UpdateCenter.java:1934)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob.replace(UpdateCenter.java:2104)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.install(UpdateCenter.java:1237)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1755)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2015)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1726)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is happening with all the plugins I am trying to install or update. I googled about it but couldn't get anything constructive.

I also installed Jenkins as standalone in the server but I am getting the same error again, which seems that it could be related to my server itself.

I was thinking to install plugins as well while the container is built through the Blue Ocean or Jenkins official image to make everything go as a code, but it seems I'll end up with the same issue.

Can someone help me to resolve it or find an alternative way to install plugins?